# How do I add a new XmlElement to an existing XmlNodeList?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.0

I have an existing XmlNodeList created using this code:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes(XPathStatement);
```

I want to add an XmlElement to the above list. I don't see any methods on `nodes` that allow this operation. How do I add the XmlElement to the XmlNodeList?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no perfect way to add an `XmlElement` to the `XmlNodeList`.

I've looked into the sources of the abstract class `XmlNodeList` and its internal descendants: `XmlElementList`, `XmlChildNodes` and `XPathNodeList`. There is no `Add` methods at all.

There is another descendant of the `XmlNodeList`: `CanonicalXmlNodeList`. It implements the `IList` and contains the `Add` method. But it cannot help because the `SelectNodes` method returns a `XPathNodeList` instance.

The `XPathNodeList` class instance (returning by the `SelectNodes` method) has a private field `List<XmlNode> list`, you could use reflection to access it:

```
var nodeList = xml.SelectNodes("/");
int dummy = nodeList.Count;  // IMPORTANT! Fills the private list when called

Assembly asm = typeof(XmlDocument).Assembly;
var t = asm.GetType("System.Xml.XPathNodeList");
var listField = t.GetField("list", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
List<XmlNode> list = (List<XmlNode>)listField.GetValue(nodeList);

list.Add(...);  // <- the goal!
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to a normal collection then add the new element there. This will not of course add the element to the original document.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

var lst = nodes.Cast<XmlElement>().ToList();
lst.Add(elm);
```